# DateTime multithreading UDP Sender has very different time results when re-assigning the value of DateTime object in my schedule loop

Tags: c#, c++, .net, multithreading, datetime

Summary: the only code difference between blocks is the assignment and re-assignment of the DateTime object

I have an app that sends UDP packets out on a very redamentry "schedule". I am seeing some behavior that makes me think I have a big misunderstanding about timers, threads, or some other concepts- I am trying to send out packets using the SendAllMessages() method based on a SendingSchedule List. My sending freqencies are are 12.5Hz, or just under a .1 seconds delay between each burst of messages. However, I am seeing much different values if I re-assign DateTime object within my loop in this method. Note that this method is run in 4 different tasks, so 4 different threads. The first example of my code gives the behavior I desire and expect: sending 4 packets sent at nearly the same time, then .08 seconds later I see another burst of 4 messages. The second example of code shows messages at a much slower rate, but I don't understand why. I thought both would behave identically. Is my "time" object being shared between threads somehow in my second example, or is something else happening?

WorkingCode (burst of 4 messages followed by waiting .08 seconds before another burst):

```
private static void SendAllMessages(List<DataMessageFormat> dataMessageList, UDPSender udpSender, byte[] first4bytes, int messageSize, bool loopContinuously = false)
{
    // pass inetMessageList to DataMessageEncoder
    MessageDataEncoder dataMessageEncoder = new MessageDataEncoder();

    List<byte[]> byteArrayListDataMessage = dataMessageEncoder.ConvertFromFormatToByteArray(dataMessageList, first4bytes, messageSize, switchDefaultEndian);

    Console.WriteLine("Sending " +  first4bytes + " UDP Messages on Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    do
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArrayListDataMessage.Count; i++) // all message lists must have the same count for this to work
        {
            DateTime time = start.AddSeconds(dataMessageEncoder.SendingSchedule[i]);
        Send:
            if (DateTime.Now > time)
            {
                udpSender.SendUDPOnce(byteArrayListDataMessage[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                goto Send;
            }
        }
    } while (loopContinuously);
}
```

The below code waits a very long time between bursting 4 messages, almost like the threads are all waiting on the same DateTimeObject:

```
   private static void SendAllMessages(List<DataMessageFormat> dataMessageList, UDPSender udpSender, byte[] first4bytes, int messageSize, bool loopContinuously = false)
{
    // pass inetMessageList to DataMessageEncoder
    MessageDataEncoder dataMessageEncoder = new MessageDataEncoder();

    List<byte[]> byteArrayListDataMessage = dataMessageEncoder.ConvertFromFormatToByteArray(dataMessageList, first4bytes, messageSize, switchDefaultEndian);

    Console.WriteLine("Sending " +  first4bytes + " UDP Messages on Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    do
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArrayListDataMessage.Count; i++) // all message lists must have the same count for this to work
        {
            time = time.AddSeconds(dataMessageEncoder.SendingSchedule[i]);
        Send:
            if (DateTime.Now > time)
            {
                udpSender.SendUDPOnce(byteArrayListDataMessage[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                goto Send;
            }
        }
    } while (loopContinuously);
}
```

Below is my good code resulting screenshot of wireshark
[image: Good timing aka first block of code]

Below is my Bad code resulting screenshot of wireshark

[image: Bad slow timing aka second block of code]

Just to give you an idea of what this app is doing:
[image: Console App simple 1000ft view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both codes have different logic:

First: the time value you are comparing is the initial time plus the schedule. Once you hit the desired time, probably the `if` test will always be true and you send the entire `byteArrayListDataMessage.Count` elements.

Second: every step of the `for` loop creates moving target so only one element gets sent.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right about it just being a logic problem. But all messages in byteArrayListDataMessage iterable would only get sent all at the same time if the SendingSchedule[] elements were not incrementing as the index increased. Your answer lead me to the problem, so have an upvote and accepted answer :)